# Установка Ubuntu 15.04 на место 14.04 LTS рядом с Windows 8.1 (Dual-Boot)

Tags: windows, ubuntu, grub, dual-boot

Прошу совета в следующем вопросе: имеется SSD на который установлена Windows 8.1, а так же HDD, от которого отрезан кусок и отдан под Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. Загрузчик (GRUB) установлен на SSD и используется при запуске ПК.

**Вопрос**: Как себя поведёт GRUB и что случится с существующими записями в нём, если я сейчас загружусь с флэшки, на которую записана 15.04, и установлю с форматированием 15.04 на (HDD) ранее созданные разделы под 14.04 LTS? Не получится ли так, что GRUB не увидит запись для Windows, тем самым я потеряю возможность запускать эту ОС, и мне придётся восстанавливать загрузчик Windows вместо GRUB, что, собственно, и поставит точку на моих экспериментах.

Comment: Да ничего скорее всего не случится, в крайнем случае может понадобиться произвести повторный поиск через `update-grub`

Comment: @Lol4t0 спасибо за ваш ответ, но хотелось бы знать наверняка. Подожду ответа от других участников.

Comment: Некоторое время назад говорили про ошибку в инсталляторе убунту, что вместо форматирования одного раздела, он отформатирует всё, до чего доберётся (про какие именно версии шла речь версии не помню). Осторожнее.

Comment: @Qwertiy где говорили? Хочется ознакомиться.

Comment: Если б я помнил, где... Всё, что сейчас нагуглил указывает источником http://www.cnews.ru/news/top/index.shtml?2014/08/29/584343 Надеюсь, к 15й версии это не относится.

Answer (score 2):

Спасибо участнику [Lol4t0](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/176769/lol4t0). Его ответ оказался самым полезным. Только что закончил проводить описанные в шапке манипуляции и в итоге получил неработающий GRUB, но всё решил благодаря команде:

```
update-grub
```

В итоге загрузчик восстановился и Windows без проблем запускается как и раньше.